# Different Api version android

Tags: android, android-library, minimumosversion

I am trying to use [ParallaxPagerLibrary](https://github.com/xgc1986/ParallaxPagerLibrary) which has minimum sdk version 11. I am supporting min sdk version 8.I want to use this library for sdk version > 11 and normal view pager for sdk version < 11. I don't know how do code according to sdk version. Any suggestions?